# How to refer to a field of a Class in other Class?

Tags: android, kotlin

There is integer variable 'a' in Class A, and method

```
Class A {
  var a = 0
  fun setA(int: Int) {
    a = int
  }
}
```

I used it in Class B by

```
Class B {
  var classA = A()
  classA.setA(10)
}
```

Then I want to set a to `100` in another class, Class C

But If I declare classA as A() and classA.setA(100) in same method of B, this doesn't change value of `a` referred in class B.

How to globally change the value of `a` in one place so that it's the same for all other classes?

Comment: Class C has to hold the a.reference of B that is the same that is holding the reference to A

Comment: Also, you can make `A` an object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class A {
    companion object {
        var a: Int = 0
    }
}
```

perhaps you're looking for a `companion` object ? this allows global access to the same instance of `a`

you can now do:

```
A.a = 5
```

or in your case :

```
fun changeValue(int: Int) {
    a = int
}
```

and this value will be the same everywhere

if you're trying to read the value back:

```
    var example = A.a
```

note how I'm not creating an instance of `A` anywhere, because using a companion object is the same as using static in java, basically meaning that you can treat this as if an instance already exists